# Recompile a part of the built-in apps

Tags: java, android

I have a rooted-Android-4.2.2 Samsung Core Plus SM-G350 device.
I want to change only 5 lines in the source code of `android.process.media`, i.e. the Media Scanner built-in app.

**Is it possible to recompile this small core built-in app, and upload it to my phone, without having to rebuild a whole custom ROM?**

What's the general principle for recompiling a system-core app on Android?

---

*Why? For reasons too-long to discuss here, I really need to use this [abandonned patch](https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/31110/2/media/java/android/media/MediaScanner.java). This is linked to the famous ".nomedia" file bug discussed in many places, such as [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24162).*

Comment: This is on-topic here, but you might have better luck on the Android SE.

Comment: I thought about Android SE, but eventually I thought it would be more on topic here, because more programming-centered than device-enthusiast.

Comment: It's possible if you have the source to that app.  Do you?

Comment: @user3137702 I'm using Android 4.2.2 Kernel 3.4.5-2722265 se.infra@SEP-132 #1 Fri Jul 25 16:36:14 KST 2014 . Do you think that with this we can find it ? Or maybe I could try to adapt the official Android 4.2.2  file to match this change : https://android-review.googlesource.com/#/c/31110/2/media/java/android/media/MediaScanner.java

Comment: It might be worth trying @user3137702 ? If I have the code, how to build just the Media Scanner and replace my phone's Media Scanner with the new ? (rooted phone)